# Can we use another thread to execute a outside executable

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering if it is possible to start another execuatable using another thread. Start another process is resource intensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking how to launch the process in the background (so that your UI doesn't freeze), you can write

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { Process.Start("notepad.exe"); });
```

---

If you're asking to execute the process inside your process' space, that's utterly impossible for arbitrary programs and a very bad idea for managed programs.

Answer (score 3):

If you start another executable from another thread, you will start a new process. I think you are confusing the relationship between threads, processes and executables somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

By nature, an executable must run in it's own process.  You could however launch a method from another thread in an executable since it itself is just an assembly.

Threads share the address space of the process that created it; processes have their own address.

To do so, you'd need to make the referenced exe a `friend assembly`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Or use [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=VS.90).aspx

Straight out of MSDN Documentation

```
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
            // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
            // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
            // from this application using the Kill method.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Is that what you mean?